# C++ build artifacts management

Tags: c++, jenkins, continuous-integration, artifacts

We are moving our build and testing system to Jenkins, and are looking for an easy way (where we don't have to code all the logic ourselves) to manage the build artifacts.

Basically we need an organised way to store them in order by the type of the build, the user who built it and such for example:

```
johnd/nightly/r543241/win32/program.zip
johnd/nightly/trunk/lin64/program.tar.gz
master/release/2.1/win32/program.zip
```

This way we can upload when a build is complete, and retrieve the required artifact in the testing stage with ease.

Until now we simply stored the files in directories on NFS, but recently started considering an artifact manager. I've looked at Artifcatory, Archiva and Nexus. But all seem very Java centered or at least required maven to work with. Since I don't want to introduce more complexity (We mainly work with python, scons is our build tool) and I don't want to introduce maven to the mix, I'm looking for something that has an easy command line (or better REST/Python interface) to upload, download, manage artifacts.

If you don't use an artifact manager, but use some other clever method to manage your C++ artifacts for release/test needs I'd be happy to hear that also.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue. I didn't succeed to integrate artifactory easilly, so I forgot it.

For the moment I use the copy artefact plugin to copy by scp the file to an NFS share. But this is not a good solution since shares may be mounted differently on two machines, and windows cannot access them directly.

But a real artifact manager would be so such a good thing for our project.

In my previous job, I was using a documentation CMS (LiveLink) which provided good services:
- self organising folder. 
- persistant url (we can move, rename folders and files, a public URL to a given files never changes, that was SOOO great : "http://server/go/123456789123456789" always pointed to the same file. So you just had to give this url to wget and you get the file
- file versionning.
- meta data, advanced search

I'm still searching such a solution in opensource software and don't find it.

In you just need to share artefact between two jobs, simple use the "copy artifact for another build" plugin. I use it to split my job into a a build job and a test job (actually there are 3 test jobs, one very fast done after each commit, one quite slow done every day, and one very slow done each week end).